# Notify someone as they near their question ban

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

Today I was banned from asking questions because some people 'down voted' my question. I wasn't warned by StackOverflow that if I ask another question which may be of poor quality, then I will be banned from asking questions..

So I went to go ask a question and was presented with the: "This account can no longer ask questions"

My request/feature is that there is a notification bar just below the navigation bar which informs the user of this, or even better: attach it to the ask question button so that they are prompted before they ask the question, which may ultimately ban them.

Comment: [Suggestion] A __shortcut__ to _avoid_ the ban : take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: This is what you should have seen: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/

Comment: @nkjt Somehow I missed your comment and ended up asking for the same in the [below comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290585/notify-someone-as-they-near-their-question-ban/290588?noredirect=1#comment178459_290588). :-)

Answer (score 12):

You should have received warnings. In fact, looking at your history it says that you did when you posted [your last question an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696516/android-npe-issue), and that was not the only time you were warned.

Are you sure you never saw this warning as you were composing your last question?

Comment: I'm positive. There were no indications that I would have been banned. If I saw the warning, I would have checked my question over a couple of times.

Comment: @BC If i'm not asking too much, a rough screenshot pointing to the apperance (position) of the message may greatly help OP to verify his/her 'positive'ness. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - This is what you should be presented with: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118

Comment: @BradLarson Exactly. Perfect Addition. Can't this link be added in the answer itself?