# Some way to find out how far off you are from asking/answering ban lift

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

To clarify, what I'm asking is sometimes when a user has a certain amount of downvoted questions/answers, they are locked out from asking new questions, or answering depending on the quality of their previous respective posts - i.e. you ask bad questions - you can't ask more; you give bad answers - you can't give more; until you fix up what has already been provided.

*So*, my question is: is there a way to know how far off you are from being able to ask/answer once you've been "locked out"?

Comment: Sort of addressed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290585/notify-someone-as-they-near-their-question-ban).

Comment: The algorithm is secret to avoid gaming the system, but as you near the throttle or ban you should get some notices,

Comment: see also: [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days)

Comment: @gnat not a duplicate of the question in your first link (nor the question linked by alexforrence): this is the opposite. However the question in your second link, being a different question, has [an answer for this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271543/4904830), in "How is the length of time that I'm limited actually calculated?".

Comment: you can close as duplicate of a question containing answer that addresses your question (as an asker, you can do it [singlehandedly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297547/839601) - '...you can flag for closing as a duplicate and if you get the notification that the questions is being closed, answer "yes" to the question and it'll be closed straight away')